# What kind of conditional are these sentences?

Tags: conditionals

> 1. If he really **is** my clone, he would never want that
> 2. If that’**s** the case, I would recommend the Capillary Caves to the west.

I've seen these sentences in an Anime called [Gin Tama](https://wiki2.org/en/List_of_Gintama_episodes?s=Gintama%20-%20169) and I think they are OK, but I don't know if they are conditional or a mess of the captions.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some punctuation will clarify the first sentence:

- If he really is my clone, [then] he would never want that.

Given the condition is true, the speaker's opinion is that the clone would not want (something or another).

The second is missing a word:

- If that [were] the case, I would recommend ...

The second is a subjunctive missing the actual subjunctive verb, meant to explore the hypothetical situation where X is the case.

Comment: You were absolutely right about the punctuation. The OP had copied the sentences incorrectly OR they have since been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the second sentence there should be 'that is...'.
2. Both sentences are a mixture of two Conditionals:

The subordinate clauses are in the first Conditional Mood (which refers to the real present or future condition).

The main clauses are in the second Conditional Mood (which refers to the unreal hypothetical result in the future).